# How can I fetch from 2 different table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Im trying to combine both ***labeled2015***    and ***labeled2019***
with if `diseasetype = 3`

Here sample of my query

```
SELECT * from labeled2019 labeled2015 inner join dataaaaa on diseasetype = 3 ;
```

Here my Tables:

[image: Here my Tables]

Sample of labeled2015:

[image: Sample of labeled2015]

Sample of labeled2019:

[image: Sample of labeled2019]

***dataaaaa*** table is empty.
By the way its not necessary to put query result in to ***dataaaaa*** table. Showing the result is enough.

Note that it gives me the *[42702] ERROR: column reference "diseasetype" is ambiguous* error.

Expected result:

Getting all the photo names whose diseasetype = 3

```
photoname | diseasetype
32_left          3
asdf433sd        3
```

Comment: Please provide desired result

Comment: Obviously both table has the common column(`diseasetype`) without qualified by an alias of those tables. eg. Alias the tables such as `SELECT * FROM labeled2019 l9 JOIN labeled2015 l5 ON l5.diseasetype = l9.diseasetype WHERE l5.diseasetype = 3` ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan It worked but it give me the result with 4 column I just want a result that has 2 colum which are just *photoname* and *diseasetype*. I mean 2019 and 2015 datas should be combined.

Comment: This seems like a bad design. It would probably be better solution to have one table for all years with a new column year

Comment: That was just an example to reproduce the scenario while giving you an idea to spot the current error, so didn't list each column explicitly next to the SELECT keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 'union' operator. It can join query results from multiple tables into one result.
So query will look kind of like this:

```
SELECT * 
from labeled2015 
where diseasetype = 3
union
SELECT * 
from labeled2019 
where diseasetype = 3
```

See the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html

Comment: Do never use *, especially when selecting multiple tables. Once one of the tables will have a column more or less, this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would like to get the entries of the two tables as separate lines, this will be easier when just using `UNION ALL` or `UNION` instead of JOIN.

```
SELECT photoname, diseasetype FROM labeled2015 WHERE diseasetype = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT photoname, diseasetype FROM labeled2019 WHERE diseasetype = 3
```

`UNION ALL` is faster and should be prefered, but doesn't remove duplicates if the same entry occurs in both tables. So take `UNION` instead if you want to rule this out.
Since you restrict your result on entries having diseasetype = 3, you can even write `SELECT photoname, 3...` in bot queries instead of the column name.

Comment: Wow thank you! Can I also ask how can I put my result to different table?

Comment: Please create a second question for this